# Error when trying to run two npm scripts combined

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I have the following scripts:

```json
"clear": "rimraf lib",
"build": "npm run clear && ./node_modules/.bin/babel --out-dir lib src",
...
```

When I run `npm run clear` works nice!

If I run `./node_modules/.bin/babel --out-dir lib src` it does what's expected.

if I run `npm run clear && ./node_modules/.bin/babel --out-dir lib src` it works fine too.

**BUT** if I run `npm run build` I get the following error:

> `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

I'm using windows 10.

npm 5.6.0

node 7.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```json
"clear": "rimraf lib",
"build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel --out-dir lib src",
"clear-build": "npm run clear && npm run build",
```

And after that to build run:

```
npm run clear-build
```